# Combine Line and Scatter charts in JavaFX for multiple number of series

Tags: java, css, javafx, charts

I have an app where the user is given plenty of options, and depending on user selection anything from 1 up to 20 scatter plots will be displayed dynamically in the same scatter chart.

I want to add a checkbox to show best fits for each of these samples, same color as the original scatter points, but then using lines.

Even though I like the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26805320/5069105), it solves the problem "statically", i.e. for small and fix number of series.

Is there a way to automate this solution for a large and dynamically changing number of series?

I'd rather not use superimposed charts and setting transparency, unless I really have to.

Comment: You can use the techniques in my answer to [this question[(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871202/how-to-add-shapes-on-javafx-linechart) to add lines to a scatter chart.

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26803380/how-to-combine-scatter-chart-with-line-chart-to-show-line-of-regression-javafx/26805320#26805320) , if you want to create a Scatter chart with line regression ( linear or polynomial ) have a look to my own implementation of a  [Multi-Axis-Scatter-Chart](https://github.com/JKostikiadis/MultiAxisScatterChart) maybe you will take some ideas about your problem. I am not sure about what you need cause do be honest I didn't understand your question at 100%. I hope my own implementation might help you somehow.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting library! Even though I'm not really interested in multi-y-axis charts, your example `chart.showLinearTrendLineOnAxis()` do what I'm after - scatter + line charts. Apparently the trend lines are a fine scatter plot drawing directly to canvas in `MultiAxisScatterChart.drawPoint`. Is that correct?

Comment: To hide the second Y-Axis, would be very easy thing to do ;). 
The library logic is as you said. Indeed the trend lines are consecutive "points" drawn to the canvas. Giving the illusion of a line or a curve. If you need any help just ask me. It's an old project of mine but i am sure i can help you with ;)